# Why [K : Q] is at most 6

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let f(x) = x^3 + 3x + 1. Show that f has only one real root. What is the Galois group of f isomorphic to? (Note: you do not need to do any explicit computations to determine the Galois group.)

Solution: First notice that f is irreducible over Q (for example by checking mod 2). Since f(x) is cubic, it has a real root. Moreover, since f′(x) = 3x^2 + 3 is positive for all x, f is always increasing, so it has only one real root. Let α be the unique real root of f(x). Then Q(α)/Q has degree 3. Moreover, Q(α) is not a splitting field for f because its other roots are not real. So its splitting field is an extension K/Q(α). Since [K : Q] is at most 6, and it’s not 3, it must be exactly 6. Therefore K/Q has Galois group isomorphic to S3 since it’s a subgroup of S3 of order |S3|.

I understand most parts of the proof. However, I don't see why [K : Q] is at most 6? That is, how do I estimate the [K : Q]?

Comment: In $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ we have $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$ for some $g(x)$ of degree $2$. $K$ results from $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ by adjoining a root of $g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obtain $K$ by adjoining the three roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ to $\mathbb Q$. 
When you adjoin $\alpha$, it is a degree $3$ extension (as explained in the proof). 
Then you adjoin $\beta$, which is a root of the quadratic polynomial $f(x)/(x-\alpha) \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. So the degree of $\beta$ is at most $2$. 
Finally, after adjoining $\beta$, you are left with $\gamma$, which is now in the extended field (as it is the root of the unary polynomial $f(x)/((x-\alpha)(x-\beta))\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$).

In general, the argument yields that the splitting field of an $n$-ary polynomial is an extension of degree at most n!.